# Naming exception when attempting to configure hibernate on a tomcat server

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jndi

> EDIT: A solution to this problem has been found, the issue was that in
>   persistence.xml, the data-source-name needed to be prefixed with
>   java:comp/env/ like so: java:comp/env/jdbc/TSDB

I know this is a well documented issue, however, after many different attempts and ample reading, i still cannot configure a datasource to be used by Hibernate.

I am trying to develop a Tomcat application server which uses hibernate to connect to a MySQL server.

I am using Eclipse Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Hibernate: 5.4.1.Final
Mysql connector: 8.0.14
SERVER: Apache Tomcat/9.0.14

The datasource is defined in server.xml:

```
  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxTotal="100" 
    maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" minIdle="5" name="jdbc/TSDB" password="PASSWORD" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tstest?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" username="USERNAME"/>


  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

Web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/TSDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Context.xml:

```
<Context>
        <ResourceLink name="jdbc/TSDB" global="jdbc/TSDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</Context>
```

Persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="TsPersistence" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/TSDB</jta-data-source>

        <!-- Entity Classes Mappings -->
        <class>com.ts.hibernate.entities.User</class>
        <!-- EO Entity Classes Mappings -->

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Then when i try to create an entity manager in a web listener:

```
@WebListener
public class HibernateSessionFactoryListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HibernateSessionFactoryListener.class);

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {


        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TsPersistence");
        servletContextEvent.getServletContext().setAttribute("EntityManagerFactory", entityManagerFactory);

        logger.info("Entity Manager Configured Successfully!");
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Feb 15, 2019 12:00:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.ts.hibernate.listeners.HibernateSessionFactoryListener]
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "TsPersistence" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider, org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl from provider: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createPersistenceException(Persistence.java:244)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:186)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:72)
    at com.ts.hibernate.listeners.HibernateSessionFactoryListener.contextInitialized(HibernateSessionFactoryListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4663)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5131)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:933)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:637)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:903)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:934)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:152)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [jdbc/TSDB]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/TSDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:140)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:413)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:97)
```

Is there any additional configuration i need to create? 
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `GlobalNamingResource` element declared in the `server.xml` file is equivalent ([Docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/globalresources.html)) to the `resource-ref` declared in the `web.xml` file. I'd say **remove** the one inside `web.xml`

```
<resource-ref>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/TSDB</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: @monkeyStix is your `context.xml` file under `META-INF/`?

Comment: eventually it appears i needed to add java:comp/env/ to <jta-data-source>jdbc/TSDB</jta-data-source>, i will edit the question to include the solution for future referance